# xcode bug deployment target

Tags: swift, xcode, mapbox-ios

I am trying to implement mapbox Vision SDK. I set deployment target 11.2, also in pod file 11.2 but I get error Compiling for iOS 9.0, but module 'MapboxVision' has a minimum deployment target of iOS 11.2:

How to resolve this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

iOS development target was 9.0 under project target

Answer (score 0):

We need to set the correct deployment target in two places,

1. Project > Target > Deployment Info> Target
2. Project > Project Name > Deployment Target

[image: Proj>Proj>DeplymentInfo]

[image: Proj>Target>DeploymentInfo>Target]